# RegEx Split into sections then match strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a pretty big text file that contains single quoted strings between brackets.

```
[
'stringIneedToExtractBetweenSingleQuotes' some other 
text 
and 
characters asdasf/*- 'AnotherStringIneedToExtract'
]

[
'anotherstring' some other 
text and characters asdasfds/*- 'PleaseExtractMe'
]

[...]
```

I would like to get the strings between quotes in the separated sections delimited by brackets, like array indexes,

`$array[0]` or `$matches[0]`

```
stringIneedToExtractBetweenSingleQuotes

AnotherStringIneedToExtract
```

`$array[1]` or `$matches[1]`

```
anotherstring

PleaseExtractMe
```

Using `'(.*?)'` I can extract all the strings between single quotes but I'm not sure which one makes sense to use:

1. Use PowerShell `.split(']')` method to split the text into arrays then use `'(.*?)'` to extract the strings.
2. Most preferred way (if it's possible), use regex to extract these strings and split into sections using [ ] as a delimiter.

Comment: I don't think you need to split the string, just use capture groups after you have run your regex.
https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/30/regex-groups-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: _pretty big text file_ is subjective. Can you quantify that with number or lines or average file size?

Comment: Are there any single quotes string _outside_ the brackets in your file? Or does the presence of the brackets not really need to be taken into account?

Comment: Tamás, thanks for the article, I already use $matches[...] variable but it gives me each match separately. I would like to get them each [  ] section not each string match.

@Matt file size is ~95-100 MB, there are no single quotes or any text outside the brackets. 

I thought I can use the brackets as a boundary to get each quoted string inside a bracket then save into an array and use each section with array indexes. So, I can access the quoted strings between first brackets using $array[0] or $matches[0], 2nd brackets using $array[1] or $matches[1] and so on.

Comment: So there is always a pair of quoted strings in each bracket block then?

Comment: Some brackets have multiple quoted strings.

For now I use,
`(Get-Content -raw .\text.log).split(']')[0] |
select-string -pattern '(.*?)' -AllMatches | foreach {$_.matches.value}`

So if I change split index number I get each bracket section.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a large file, I'd use `Get-Content` with `-Readcount` to reduce the I/O operations. Then you can use chained `-match` and `-replace` as array operators to filter and then extract the required data:

```
$ExtractedLines=
Get-Content .\testdata.txt -ReadCount 1000 |
ForEach-Object {$_ -match ".*'.+'.*" -replace ".*'(.+)'.*",'$1'}
```

Edit:

If you want to keep the square brackets:

```
$ExtractedLines=
Get-Content .\testdata.txt -ReadCount 1000 |
ForEach-Object {$_ -match ".*'.+'.*|[\[\]]" -replace ".*'(.+)'.*",'$1'}
```

Then split that up using the square brackets as delimiters.

Comment: Thanks @mjolinor


I just got many true and false output, may I ask, why do you use -replace and what is the $1 variable in replace?

Comment: Are you using the -ReadCount 1000 option on Get-Content?  Without that (or with a ReadCount of 1 which is the default) you will get the true/false returns.  I'm using -replace to remove all the text that's outside of the single quotes. The $1 represents the first capture group, which is the text inside the single quotes.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Now it works with -ReadCount

Now, do you know how can I group the strings using brackets? for example $array[0] will contain strings between the first brackets, currently I use following to group the strings between brackets,

`(Get-Content -raw .\text.log).split(']')[0] | select-string -pattern '(.*?)' -AllMatches | foreach {$_.matches.value}`

This gives me matched strings between the first [ ]

Comment: Are you wanting $array[0] to be another array, or just a multi-line string?

Comment: Actually, following one-liner is doing exactly what I want. Separating each brackets then getting quoted strings, so I can access each bracket(strings) using array index like `split(']')[14]`

**Oneliner I use:** `(Get-Content -raw .\text.log).split(']')[0] | select-string -pattern "'(.*?)'" -AllMatches | foreach {$_.matches.value}`

My question is, is there a better way to do this using PowerShell, or is it possible to do the same thing with regex without using PS split?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  "Better" will depend on the circumstances.  I can tell you that your one-liner is going to read the entire file into memory. If you have enough available resources it'll work fine. If not then you're going to start seeing performance issues or the whole thing may just collapse due to memory exhaustion. The solution I offered was designed to avoid that, since you indicated that you were working with a large file.

Comment: So far I was working with a template file, as you said -ReadCount parameter makes a big performance difference on the main text file. Thanks.